# What is the "lower bound average gain" metric used in GMM stopping criterion used in Scikit learn?

Tags: references, scikit-learn, terminology, gaussian-mixture-distribution, generative-models

In Scikit Learn's GMM class, it says that GMM training algorithm stops according to the "lower bound average gain"

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html

After some digging, almost all references to this term traces back to this doc.

Does anyone know what this function might be alluding to? I think knowing the precise stopping criterion for GMM is quite important in practice.

Comment: The [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html#estimation-algorithm-variational-inference) gets into some details.